# How to query JSON in EC2 using Athena?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have an IoT structure running inside AWS. I am using the AWS Broker that trigger off a Lambda function that sends the Thing message to an instance trough a nodeJs API. I could use S3 to store the log but I would like to test a storage system inside a EC2 Instance.

Now the point is how to make Athena able to query those JSON files stored  inside this EC2 instance. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Athena can only query data stored in Amazon S3.

You could need to copy the data from the Amazon EC2 instance to an Amazon S3 bucket before being able to query it with Amazon Athena.